# Is there a way to see summarized data by range?

Tags: r

I have a data set consisting of

```
Age  Income  Expenses
25   $200    $100
30   $300    $150
35   $500    $300
40   $200    $50
45   $500    $100
50   $1000   $500
```

I want to know if it's possible to find the mean of Income and Expenses by ranges, let's say 25-35, 36-50. So, from ages 25-35 average income is $500, average expenses $183.

Thanks

I've tried several formulas, but none seem to the trick

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table like you have). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg. You can also simply create the data by scratch in R and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- tibble::tribble(~Age,  ~Income, ~ Expenses,
25 ,  200,    100,
30 ,  300,    150,
35 ,  500,    300,
40 ,  200,    50,
45 ,  500,    100,
50 ,  1000,   500)

library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(age_cat = case_when(Age < 35 ~ "Under 35",
                             Age < 45 ~ "35 to 44",
                             TRUE ~ "45 and over"),
         age_cat = forcats::fct_relevel(age_cat, "Under 35", "35 to 44", "45 and over")) |> 
  group_by(age_cat) |> 
  summarize(across(c(Income, Expenses), mean))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  age_cat     Income Expenses
  <fct>        <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Under 35       250      125
2 35 to 44       350      175
3 45 and over    750      300
```